# How to use site_url() in Elementor

Tags: plugins, site-url

I have created  a website in wordpress, which is currently running as sub domain of a company.  This website contains large number of pdf documents, which are belongs to different categories. The pdf's are placed in a page called downloads, which is created using elementor plugin. I have included a button to download every pdf. The link of button which is like `http://domain_name/subdomain/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/pdf_name.pdf`. I want to purchase a domain for my site. And How to change the link address to `http://my_domain/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/pdf_name.pdf`. Whether we can represent the ***site home*** address like ***base_url()*** in **codeignitor**?. I tried 
`<?php echo home_url()?>` and `<?php echo site_url()?>`. But it only added to the current url address as **echo%20site_url()**. How to change it using the site address.

[image: Image of button with document heading and description]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Help Screenshot]

Click on **Dynamic** on top right of link field for the button, select **Site URL** from the dropdown and you are good to go. The button link won't change even when you change the site domain.

Comment: This just links to the current page for me. Totally useless feature.